# Floating Iframe on mobile with android

Tags: android, mobile, iframe, floating

I've encountered some problem with Iframe on mobile devices using android. It appears, that the iframe is ingoring everythng in my css files or even direct styling. It simply put itselfs in the left top corner over all content. 
Nothing helps me get it out of that place, not margin, absolute position or anything else.
Even when I wrap that iframe with div a set absolute position to that div, nothing change.

Does anybody have n idea,what this could do?